# How to marshall JAXBElement<Object> into org.w3c.dom.Element in Java using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, element

I need to get Element object with request. I have ObjectFactory. I created an JAXBElement, and I need to marshall it to Element. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could marshal to a `DOMResult`:

```
DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
marshaller.marshal(myJaxbElement, res);
Element elt = ((Document)res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ian's answer, I suppose to first create a Document, as the unchecked cast can be omitted this way:

```
Document document =
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
JAXB.marshal(jaxbElement, new DOMResult(document));
Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
```