# How to Marshall Object to Element

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to mashall an object to org.w3c.dom.Element, but it's not working.
Here's my code:

```
public static org.w3c.dom.Element writeXMLElement(Object nf) {
    JAXBContext context;
    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Rodo.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        org.w3c.dom.Element retorno = new org.w3c.dom.Element() {

            ...
        };
        marshaller.marshal(nf, retorno);
        return retorno;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I write XML file, it works fine. But to Element I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.SAX2DOMEx.startElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.SAXOutput.endStartTag(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.endAttributes(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
>       at XMLWriter.writeXMLElement(XMLWriter.java:388)
>       at HTMLCTeParse.getCTeBean(HTMLCTeParse.java:339)
>       at GeraCTe.main(GeraCTe.java:12)

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you! Br

Comment: Are you sure that `Object nf` is not `null`?

Comment: If you marshal the same instance to `System.out` instead what does the XML look like, or do you still get an error?

Comment: Marshal to System.out works fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other solution:

[How to marshall JAXBElement<Object> into org.w3c.dom.Element in Java using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569572/how-to-marshall-jaxbelementobject-into-org-w3c-dom-element-in-java-using-jaxb)

> You could marshal to a DOMResult:
>
> DOMResult res = new DOMResult(); marshaller.marshal(myJaxbElement,
>   res); Element elt = ((Document)res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();

Thank you anyway. :)